# Azure API Management Service Set body Policy - modify JSON response to return certain fields

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Based on

[Azure API Management Service "Set body" Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody)

We can modify the response of an API service. For Eg., instead of returning below :

```
{ 
  "company" : "Azure",
  "service" : "API Management"
}
```

We would only like to return :

```
{ "company" : "Azure" }
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this as I have no idea what kind of programming language / syntax they are using in their documentation as shown below :

```
<set-body>  
@{   
    string inBody = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);   
    if (inBody[0] =='c') {   
        inBody[0] = 'm';   
    }   
    return inBody;   
}  
</set-body>
```

Comment: i believe its c#, i mean, it looks and feels like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you look at is called `Policy expressions` and is well described on the [official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions). A short quote from the site states:

> Policy expressions syntax is C# 6.0. Each expression has access to the
>   implicitly provided context variable and an allowed subset of .NET
>   Framework types.

A more appropriate sample in the `set-body` [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) would be the one that filters output:

```
<!-- Copy this snippet into the outbound section to remove a number of data elements from the response received from the backend service based on the name of the api product -->  
    <set-body>@{  
        var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();  
        foreach (var key in new [] {"minutely", "hourly", "daily", "flags"}) {  
          response.Property (key).Remove ();  
        }  
        return response.ToString();  
      }  
    </set-body>
```

To customise that for your specific object - you want to remove the `service` property:

```
    <set-body>@{  
        var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();  
        foreach (var key in new [] {"service"}) {  
          response.Property (key).Remove ();  
        }  
        return response.ToString();  
      }  
    </set-body>
```

Comment: <set-body>@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))</set-body> I have this in my inbound request. I want to only only 's in data and if another combination exist I want to reject Request. How this can be accomplished

Comment: @astaykov I tried to use this as in the documentation but in my case it is returning an http 500, saying "Expression evaluation failed. 'UTF8' is not valid encoding name\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.PipelineMessage.GetEncoding(Encoding defaultValue)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.As[T](Boolean preserveContent)",
        null,
        "'UTF8' is not valid encoding name"